# How to run tensorflow using GPU?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Tensorflow version - 1.0.1
GPU version - 1.0.1
python - 3.6
Graphics(Ubuntu 18.04) - Intel® Sandybridge Desktop
We are trying to run a python code using Tensorflow. But it was very slow. So, we would like to run the code on GPU. Can anyone suggest how to use GPU for running python code?

Comment: You could check this out: [using GPUs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu). You could also try out Google Colab if you want

Comment: There is a different package for that. If you have all other prerequisites install it with pip install TensorFlow-gpu you do not need to change your code, TensorFlow should handle the gpu on its own. But not everything runs faster on a gpu. Only if you are e.g. training a net (tasks that can run in parallel)

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall tensor flow and install the GPU compatible version with

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Answer (score 0):

```
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(gpu_options = tf.compat.v1.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.8))
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(session)
```

Place this code before your python code and also make sure you have all the cuDNN dlls installed.